# Boton 'Registrar' no me dirige a archvo PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html5, post

He estado trabajando en un formulario con HTML; las validaciones las hice con Javascript, pero al momento de dar click al Botón de 'Registrar' no se me dirige al archivo PHP.

Espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias!

1.Este es mi código HTML.

```
<body>
<form class="form-register" id="idFormulario" action="action.php" method="POST">
    <h2 class="form__titulo">Crea una cuenta</h2>
    <div class="container-inputs">
        <input type="text"  id="idNombre"    name="txtNombre"    placeholder="Nombre"    class="input-48" maxlength="50">
        <input type="text"  id="idApellido"  name="txtApellido"  placeholder="Apellidos" class="input-48" maxlength="50">
        <input type="email" id="idCorreo"   name="txtCorreo"    placeholder="Email"     class="input-100" maxlength="50">
        <input type="text"  id="idTelefono"  name="txtTelefono"  placeholder="Telefono"  class="input-100" maxlength="10" >
        <input type="text"  id="idUsuario"   name="txtUsuarios"  placeholder="Usuario"   class="input-48"  maxlength="10">
        <input type="password" id="idPassword" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Contraseña" class="input-48" maxlength="15">
        <div id="idRespuesta" class="clsRespuesta"></div>
        <input type="submit"  id="idBoton"  name="btnEnviar" value="Registrar" class="btnEnviar" >
        <p class="form__link">¿Ya tienes una cuenta?<a href="">Ingresa Aquí</p>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

2. Este es el de las validaciones con JS. PD: Las validaciones las estoy haciendo en un archivo .js .

```js
var formulario, nombre, apellido, correo, telefono, usuario, password, expresion, respuesta, boton;

formulario = document.getElementById('idFormulario');
nombre = document.getElementById('idNombre');
apellido = document.getElementById('idApellido');
correo = document.getElementById('idCorreo');
telefono = document.getElementById('idTelefono');
usuario = document.getElementById('idUsuario');
password = document.getElementById('idPassword');
respuesta = document.getElementById('idRespuesta');
boton = document.getElementById('idBoton');

formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (nombre.value === "") {

    nombre.focus();
    nombre.style.borderColor = "red";

    respuesta.innerHTML = `
        <div class="alert alert-danger role="alert">
        ¡ERROR! COMPLETE TODOS LOS CAMPOS
         </div>
         `
  } else if (apellido.value === "") {
    apellido.focus();

    apellido.style.borderColor = "red";

    respuesta.innerHTML = `
            <div class="alert alert-danger role="alert">
                ¡ERROR!  COMPLETE TODOS LOS CAMPOS
            </div>
        `
  } else if (correo.value === "") {

    correo.focus();
    correo.style.borderColor = "red";

    respuesta.innerHTML = `
        <div class="alert alert-danger role="alert">
            ¡ERROR!  COMPLETE TODOS LOS CAMPOS
        </div>
    `
  } else if (telefono.value === "") {

    telefono.focus();
    telefono.style.borderColor = "red";

    respuesta.innerHTML = `
        <div class="alert alert-danger role="alert">
            ¡ERROR!  COMPLETE TODOS LOS CAMPOS
        </div>
    `
  } else if (usuario.value === "") {

    usuario.focus();
    usuario.style.borderColor = "red";

    respuesta.innerHTML = `
        <div class="alert alert-danger role="alert">
            ¡ERROR!  COMPLETE TODOS LOS CAMPOS
        </div>
        `
  } else if (password.value === "") {

    password.focus();
    password.style.borderColor = "red";


    respuesta.innerHTML = `
        <div class="alert alert-danger role="alert">
            ¡ERROR!  COMPLETE TODOS LOS CAMPOS
        </div>
    `
  }

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el método `e.preventDefault();` esta impidiendo que tu botón submit realice su acción, luego de hacer las validaciones si todas cumplen llama al evento submit

```
document.getElementById('idFormulario').submit();
```